# SQL Master Data Services database has huge leaf member staging table - can I purge old records?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, master-data-services

One of our SQL instances has a large MDS database, and virtually 100% of the size is due to a 300+ million row table named `stg.Stg_Project_Leaf`. It recently started blowing up our weekly index rebuilds, so I need to figure this out.

From what I can tell, this is a [Leaf Member Staging Table](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633854(v=sql.110).aspx) for a "Project" entity, set up and automated (by a prior consultant) as a part of an ETL process that builds BI cubes/reports.

Looks like it has been processing about 10k rows per half hour for the past *several years* and has never been purged. When I check the `ImportStatus_ID`, though, I see 0 rows waiting to be processed. (Most are 1 - succeeded, less than 1% are 2 - failed.)

**Can I just `TRUNCATE` this table?**

This system is being used in an automated fashion, its not like people are logging into the MDS console and individually monitoring and rolling back changes. I found some references to stored procedures that purge these tables (`mdm.udpStagingClear` or maybe `mdm.udpDeletedMembersPurge`), but I'm not sure which of those is the one I'd need, nor do I know if they would blow up the log if they tried to do 300m rows at once.

Comment: _Can_ you?  Sure.  ***Should*** you?  That's a question you should run by the business.  Any ability to test out the truncate in a Test environment?  I've yet to work in an environment where MDS is used as I think MS originally intended it, so this scenario doesn't shock me at all.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener But clearing *this* data staging table shouldn't impact the business in my case, right? Nobody here is using the MDS GUI to manually review and roll back old batches or anything, all they care about is whether their reports get this particular "project" data updated daily, and if I'm understanding things right, purging old import batches shouldn't effect that at all. **My** main concern is not breaking MDS if I'm not supposed to be messing with the "back end" database, but none of the documentation or tutorials I can find seem to address this.

Comment: I don't know your environment well enough to say it won't impact business, but I have done direct data manipulation to underlying MDS tables as it made more sense in my situation than going through the GUI.  Test it out in a lower environment if possible and see if anything breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short**: The *official* answer is to use the new proc `mdm.udpEntityStagingBatchTableCleanup` to clean up entity staging tables, but in practice, `DELETE` or `TRUNCATE` should work just fine (or might be necessary), as long as you understand your batch detail.

---

I found reference to a [SQL 2012 patch that adds 3 stored procedures](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3036601/fix-add-three-stored-procedures-to-clean-up-history-that-is-created-when-you-use-sql-server-2012-or-2014-mds) to MDS, including the one I need:

```
--Cleanup entity-based staging table
EXEC mdm.udpEntityStagingBatchTableCleanup @ModelID, @CleanupOlderThanDate;
```

[See also this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mds/2015/06/02/transactions-validation-issue-and-staging-table-cleanup/) for scheduled cleanup options utilizing the same procs.

For my purpose, though, I was still concerned about blowing up the tran log with the 300+ million rows that had to be deleted, so I looked in detail at the inner workings of `mdm.udpEntityStagingBatchTableCleanup`. This stored proc does the following:

1. Populates a temp table with all completed batches that match your deletion criteria (for the given `@Model_ID`, older than `@CleanupOlderThanDate`).
2. Builds dynamic `DELETE` statements for the corresponding Leaf, Consolidated, and Relationship tables for each `DISTINCT Entity_ID` in the temp table.
3. It executes each of those `DELETE` statements for each entity table, filtered via a join to the temp table.
4. It then deletes from `mdm.tblStgBatch` itself, again filtered by join to the temp table.

There is no attempt to limit the amount of rows deleted at once, and in my case,  the 300+ million rows are all for a single `Entity_ID`, which would likely blow up the transaction log.

The good news, though, is that if I intend to remove all `Entity_IDs` and all dates anyway (which I do), then that's functionally equivalent to a `TRUNCATE`,
 as long as I am careful to not attempt it right in the middle of an active batch.

Finally, while I couldn't find any official MS sources that explicitly recommended truncating these tables, I did find several articles where DBAs do a routine `TRUNCATE` at either the beginning or the end of their import process:

- ["Step 1:  Truncates each of the 3 staging tables."](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2013/2/16/importing-data-into-master-data-services-2012-part-2.html)
- ["If you want to empty the staging table, you can either delete all records, or click Clear Batches in Integration Management."](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3646/purging-entity-members-in-sql-server-master-data-services/)
- [TRUNCATE TABLE stg.TableName_Leaf](https://clinthuijbers.wordpress.com/2015/11/02/mds-how-to-truncate-an-entity-table/)

So my plan is to do an initial `TRUNCATE`, and then schedule `mdm.udpEntityStagingBatchTableCleanup` to run on a periodic basis.